# WPF - Should I prefer using Dependency Property or Method for changing state inside UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a UserControl in which I want to change UserControl state according to my application logic. To make it clear, UserControl has three states that are None, Query, Insert (Enums).

These states can be settable by developers using my UserControl. But I couldn' t decide on whether these states should be changed by using **ChangedCallback** delegates of Dependency Properties or using **separate methods** changing states like SwitchNoneState(), SwitchQueryState(), SwitchInsertState().

Here is the first approach;

```
//MyUserControl.cs
public enum States
{
    None,
    Query,
    Insert
}

public States State
{
    get { return (States)GetValue(StateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("State", typeof(States), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(States.None,StatePropertyChangedCallback));

private static void StatePropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     var control = (MyUserControl)obj;

     if (args.NewValue == null) return;

     switch ((States)args.NewValue)
     {
         case States.None:
             control.SwitchNoneState();
             break;
         case States.Query:
            control.SwitchQueryState();
             break;
         case States.Insert:
            control.SwitchInsertState();
             break;
     }
}

private SwitchNoneState()
{
    //DoSomethingAboutNoneState
}

private SwitchQueryState()
{
    //DoSomethingAboutQueryState
}

private SwitchInsertState()
{
    //DoSomethingAboutInsertState
}

//XAML using UserControl
<local:MyUserControl Name="uc" State="Query"/>
```

The Second approach;

```
//MyUserControl.cs
public enum States
{
    None,
    Query,
    Insert
}

public States State
{
    get { return (States)GetValue(StateProperty); }
}
//User can only access for state information
private static readonly DependencyProperty StatePropertyKey =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("State", typeof(States), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(States.None));

public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = StatePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

public SwitchNoneState()
{
    //DoSomethingAboutNoneState
    SetValue(StateProperty,States.None);
}

public SwitchQueryState()
{
    //DoSomethingAboutQueryState
    SetValue(StateProperty,States.Query);
}

public SwitchInsertState()
{
    //DoSomethingAboutInsertState
    SetValue(StateProperty,States.Insert);
}   


//XAML using UserControl
<local:MyUserControl Name="uc"/>

//XAML Code Behind
public void DoSomething()
{
    uc.SwitchQueryState();
}
```

What is the best practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support databinding go with Dependency Property.

Answer (score 0):

It should be settable in XAML, because that's the way you do it in XAML. That's not as dumb as it sounds -- or should I say, it's just dumb enough to be correct. This is a specific case of **Keep It Simple, Stupid**.

Every XAML control lets you set its properties in XAML, use bindings, etc., and every programmer who uses XAML learns very quickly to expect that. You don't mention your case having any uniquely exotic, profoundly compelling reasons to break that assumption, so don't break it. It's a readonly property that the user needs to set. BZZT! That's not a readonly property, it's a regular property. If it can't be changed after initialization, throw an exception if they try it when they shouldn't.

In general, when writing code in the context of somebody else's framework, write it exactly as if it were part of the framework. If it's WPF, write a WPF control that consumers could easily mistake for part of the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace. If it's Windows Forms, write an equally bland, predictable Windows Forms control.

There are two reasons for this, and they're interrelated:

1. Consumers of your code should know what to expect. Surprises waste time, create bugs, and add no value. Never make the end user think without a good reason. That logic applies to designing programming interfaces as much as user interfaces. The ideal is instant and complete recognition and understanding. You approach the ideal by making the user's prior assumptions valid as often as humanly possible, and by adding informative three-slash Intellisense comments on all your properties and methods.
2. Not only should you spare your user the need to think, but you can save yourself a great deal of thinking as well. Frameworks that see wide use tend to be well-designed by smart people who understood the domain very deeply, and refined their solution over a period of years. People like that have brought forth many dogs, but the ones that get used are generally the good ones (and if it's a bad one, minimize the pain by being awful in the expected manner). Your brilliant creative new way of writing an interface is, at best, one of the flawed ideas they discarded as impractical for reasons you'll soon be learning the hard way if you try to get clever.

Remember, the user you spare from having to think may be *you* in six months. In programming, thinking is one of the danger zones where things go horribly wrong.

The only exception is if you're not extending a framework, but replacing it with a new one: For example, jQuery breaks every assumption in sight, but it replaces them all with new ones which are (for the most part) consistently applied, and have great value of their own. Now that jQuery exists, if you're writing code to work with jQuery, write it the jQuery way.

But note also that the best way to learn not to do stupid things is to do them good and hard, and suffer thereby. One must suffer to gain mastery. A young programmer should suffer, early and often.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a style with a trigger on the state or some templates for the states?